# Checkin history of apple source code?

Tags: open-source, library

https://opensource.apple.com

I see apple source code can be browsed on line. Is there a git repo in which checkin history can be viewed?

Comment: No, they don't publish this information. The commit history probably contains many references to internal IP and security-critical information.

Comment: If I want to contact developers (for example for the following file) for problems, there is no way to do so?

https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4570.1.46/libsyscall/wrappers/renamex.c.auto.html

Comment: The best I can suggest is https://feedbackassistant.apple.com or https://developer.apple.com/forums/ or https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple just publishes the source code as a snapshot with each release of macOS. The dev repositories aren‘t public.

If you want to propose changes regarding the published code (e.g. porting a Linux system call into the Darwin/xnu kernel), use https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/